# React Hook useEffect has missing .missing dependencies: 'Score', 'props', and 'windowDimension

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, dependencies

```
useEffect(()=>{

//after game ends
if(gameEnd){
  props.gameEndHandler(Score)
}
if(!props.gameEnd){
  setScore(prev=>({
    ...prev,
    XScore: 0,
    OScore: 0,
  }));
  setGameEnd(false)

  let size = windowDimension > 620 ? 8 : 6;
  const tempClickAddress = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
    let rowValues = [];
    for (var j = 1; j <= size; j++) {
      let tempValue = {
        row: i,
        col: j,
        value: null,
        winBy: null,
      };
      rowValues.push(tempValue);
    }
    tempClickAddress.push(rowValues);
  }

  setGridData(prev=>({
    ...prev,
    clickAddress: tempClickAddress,
  }));
}}, [gameEnd, props.gameEnd]);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mO7s.png)

My chrome deve tool warns me for missing dependencies.

but i am sure about my dependency.
I just want to get rid of that warning.

Your help is immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug, it is just a warn, that you are using more variables, than you defined for useEffect reactions. And even more, this is a eslint warning, not React's.

To solve this, you should add more 'spyon' variables, e.g.:

```js
useEffect(()=>{

//after game ends
if(gameEnd){
  props.gameEndHandler(Score)
}
if(!props.gameEnd){
  setScore(prev=>({
    ...prev,
    XScore: 0,
    OScore: 0,
  }));
  setGameEnd(false)

  let size = windowDimension > 620 ? 8 : 6;
  const tempClickAddress = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
    let rowValues = [];
    for (var j = 1; j <= size; j++) {
      let tempValue = {
        row: i,
        col: j,
        value: null,
        winBy: null,
      };
      rowValues.push(tempValue);
    }
    tempClickAddress.push(rowValues);
  }

  setGridData(prev=>({
    ...prev,
    clickAddress: tempClickAddress,
  }));
}}, [gameEnd, props.gameEnd, props.gameEndHandler, setScore, setGameEnd, windowDimension, setGridData]);
```

Or you can disable the `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` rule only for this useEffect, e.g.:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  //...your code

// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, [gameEnd, props.gameEnd]);
```

Or globally at package.json:

```
{
  ...

  "eslintConfig": {
    "rules": {
      "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "off"
    }
  }
}
```